# errro in Uploading base64 image from android to server using php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, server

I am uploading an image from phone gallery to my database . I am posting the base64 string of the image to server .Here is my php code.

```
    <?php 

 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_USER', 'root');
 define('DB_PASS', '');
 define('DB_NAME', 'sample_userdata');

 //connecting to database and getting the connection object
 $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($conn)
{
    $image=$_POST["image"];
    $uploadpath="uploads/profilepic.jpg";
    if(isset($image)){
        if(file_put_contents($uploadpath,base64_decode($image))){
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image Uploaded successfully'));}

    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image upload failed'));
    }
}else{

echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image upload failed 2'));}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The image is getting saved in the uploads folder successfully and android logcat is showing the response

> D/Response: {"response":"Image Uploaded successfully"}

But the localhost/profilepic.php which contains the code is showing Notice:

> Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\profilepic.php on line 13
>   {"response":"Image upload failed"}

what is the problem , the image is successfully stored in uploads folder , android is giving success message but the localhost page is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

While hitting URL from browser `localhost/profilepic.php` is GET method. The code is excepting image via POST request.

You can add check to validate the request to avoid this warning message.

Add following code at top of your file to check image is sent or not with request

```
if( !isset($_POST["image"]) || empty($_POST["image"])
{
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image is required'));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: the browser page is now blank after adding this code , no response

Comment: Opps, I just missed to echo json response. I have updated my answer

Comment: yes but i am sending the image as base64 string so why is $image empty

Comment: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') I have added this line still not getting response

Comment: you are not getting successful response in your android code or in browser?

Comment: in the browser and successful everywhere else